# best practice to access data

Tags: c, arrays, extern

I have a function in source file 1 :
Source file 1:

```
 function in Source file 1.
    Code:
        char day[7];
    f1:
         {  
           ....
           ....
           ....
        after some work fill the
           day[0]= random number;
           .
           .
           .
           .
           day[6]=random number;     


           }     

Quote:
Source file 2:

f2:

{
extern dayval[];

//do stuff

}
```

And now i want to access those day[7] values from array in source file 2.

If i declare array as extern in source file 2 immediately after f1 in source file is executed will the values remain same or will it be zero

Well forgive my stupidity i have started learning C language just now and it's been  Quite a hell of ride Smile.
I hope you guys will enlighten me with your suggestions

Which is the best way to access data.I'm working on embedded systems and some say pass by reference is a good option.I would be delighted to have your views on it.

Regards

Comment: First of all you need to declare the `char day[7]` as global in source file 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be solved by declaring it as an `extern` variable, but it needs to be global in source1.c too. Local variables cannot be accessed from outside their scopes, at least not by name.

So, in source1.c:

```
char day[7];

void function1(void)
{
  day[0] = ...;
  /* and so on */
}
```

then in source2.c:

```
extern char day[7];

void function2(void)
{
  printf("oh, source1 has set day[0] to %c\n", day[0]);
}
```

of course, you must make sure that `function1()` from source1.c runs *before* `function2()` from source2.c, in order to initialize the array.

You could have a separate main.c that does:

```
int main(void)
{
  function1();
  function2();
  return 0;
}
```

Then compile them all together, using something like this (assuming gcc in a Unix-type environment):

```
$ gcc -o myprogram main.c source1.c source2.c
```